# Gatling Feeder running out of values

Tags: scala, gatling

I have an array that i want to use for 2 feeders. I was expecting each feeder will be able to use all the values in the array. But seems like the values run out

```
val baseArray = Array (  Map("transactionId" -> "q-1"),
            Map("transactionId" -> "q-2"),
            Map("transactionId" -> "q-3"))


val feeder_getA = baseArray.clone.queue             
val scn_getInsuredOrPrincipals = scenario("getInsuredOrPrincipals")
    .feed(feeder_getA)  
    .exec(http("request_getA").get("/getA/${transactionId}"))

val feeder_getB = baseArray.clone.queue             
val scn_getInsuredOrPrincipals = scenario("getInsuredOrPrincipals")
    .feed(feeder_getB)  
    .exec(http("request_getB").get("/getB/${transactionId}"))   



setUp(
    scn_getInsuredOrPrincipals.inject(
            atOnceUsers(3), // 2
            rampUsers(3) over (5 seconds)
    ),
    scn_getInsuredOrPrincipal.inject(
            atOnceUsers(3), // 2
            rampUsers(3) over (5 seconds)
        )
)   


I get an error saying feeder is now empty after 3 values are consumed... i was assuming feeder_getA  and feeder_getB would each get 3 values so each scenario would get equal number of values. That doesnt seem like  its happening. Almot as if the clone isnt working
```

Comment: Almost seems like the transactionId (the key of the map), becomes a session variable and, both feeders refer to one physical map.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your feeders are defined using the `queue` strategy, which runs through the elements and then fails if no more are available:

```
val feeder_getA = baseArray.clone.queue
```

You need to use the `circular` strategy, which goes back to the beginning:

```
val feeder_getA = baseArray.clone.circular
```

For more information [see the docs.](https://gatling.io/docs/3.0/session/feeder/)